# How to limit (mask) proportional editing in Blender 2.8?

Tags: edit-mode

I want to prevent proportional editing on certain vertices.
Maybe I'm searching for the wrong word or phrase.
*Limiting* editing to a certain vertex group would help.
*Masking* also gives me no search results.
I tried *locking* vertex groups, but it does not disable editing its vertices as expected.

The only answer you find is *hiding*, yet hiding is not a solution. It is -- by design :) -- making parts of the mesh invisible. 
For example if I want to close an eyelid I would need the lower lid to be visible yet not affected by editing the upper lid. 
So hiding is a workaround if you duplicate the whole mesh, but is there a solution?

Comment: I've never heard about a kind of "pinning" function, hide would be the solution, but yes it's not perfect...